# Tring to get GitHub repo via Octokit

Tags: c#, github-api, octokit.net

I'm building simple tool for downloading .lua files from online public GitHub repos via link given by user.  I started learning async methods so I wanted to test myself.

It's a console application (for now). The ultimate goal is to get .lua files in a repo and ask the user which ones he wants downloaded, but I'll be happy if I connect to GH for now.

I'm using Octokit (https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) GitHub API integration to .NET.

This is the reduced code; I removed some of unimportant stuff:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Octokit;

namespace GetThemLuas
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly GitHubClient Github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue ("Testing123"), new Uri("https://www.github.com/"));


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to GitHub repo downloader");
            GetRepoTry4();

        }

        private static async void GetRepoTry4()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Searching for data"); //returns here... code below is never ran
                var searchResults = await Github.Search.SearchRepo(new SearchRepositoriesRequest("octokit"));
                if (searchResults != null)
                    foreach (var result in searchResults.Items)
                        Console.WriteLine(result.FullName);
                Console.WriteLine("Fetching data...."); //testing search
                var myrepo = await Github.Repository.Get("Haacked", "octokit.net");
                Console.WriteLine("Done! :)");
                Console.WriteLine("Repo loaded successfully!");
                Console.WriteLine("Repo owner: " + myrepo.Owner);
                Console.WriteLine("Repo ID: " + myrepo.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Repo Date: " + myrepo.CreatedAt);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ayyyy... troubles"); //never trigged
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the await` keyword as it terminates the method and returns.

I'm still learning async methods so it's possible I messed something up, but even my ReSharper says it fine.

I used `var` to replace `task<T>` stuff. It seams OK to me plus no warnings nor errors.

I fixed the `await` issue.  Now when I finally connected to GH and tried to get the repo it threw an exeption at both calls to GH (tested with commenting first then second call). `e.message` was some huge stuff.

I logged it into a file and it looks like an HTML document. Here it is (http://pastebin.com/fxJD1dUb)

Comment: Change `GetRepoTry4();` to `Task.Run(async () => { await GetRepoTry4(); }).Wait();` and `private static async void GetRepoTry4()` to `private static async Task GetRepoTry4()`

Comment: Thank you, I just changed void to task and did this GetRepoTry().Wait();
Also tried annoymous method like you suggested and it both worked fine :)
I have a new problem now doe :S
Gonna edit my post

Comment: My guess is that root of you new problem (without actually know what the new problem is), is the lack of the `async Task` keyword pair being used correctly. Generally speaking all `async` methods need to return a `Task` or `Task<T>`; and all methods that return a `Task` or `Task<T>` should be `async`. Additionally, you should get your code into the dispatcher as quickly as possible and start using `await`.

Comment: Can you make an answer with example? Please :S

Answer (score 1):

Change `GetRepoTry4();` to `Task.Run(async () => { await GetRepoTry4(); }).Wait();` and `private static async void GetRepoTry4()` to `private static async Task GetRepoTry4()`.

This should get you at least wired up correctly enough to start debugging the real issue.

Generally speaking all `async` methods need to return a `Task` or `Task<T>` and all methods that return a `Task` or `Task<T>` should be `async`. Additionally, you should get your code into the dispatcher as quickly as possible and start using await.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor with the `Uri` overload is intended for use with GitHub Enterprise installations, e.g:

`static readonly GitHubClient Github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue ("Testing123"), new Uri("https://github.enterprise.com/"));`

If you're just using it to connect to GitHub, you don't need to specify this:

`static readonly GitHubClient Github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue ("Testing123"));`

You're seeing a HTML page because the base address is incorrect - all of the API-related operations use `api.github.com`, which is the default.

Comment: You are right! :)
Did as you said and now I got the repolist. Need to get the content now :S
Is there any kind of documentation on Octokit? Or forum or community?
Have no idea where to start :S
How can I see what's inside the repo? (myrepo object just has some stats and properties, not contents)

Comment: Repo content is fetched using Git protocol, which is implemented in Git. Sounds like you want to script Git.exe. If so, take a look at [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp).

Answer (score 0):

Install [Octokit Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Octokit/) for Github.Then add below function

```
public JsonResult GetRepositoryDeatil(long id)
{
    var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("demo"));
    var tokenAuth = new Credentials("xxxxxxx"); // NOTE: not real token
    client.Credentials = tokenAuth;
    var content = client.Repository.Content.GetAllContents(id).Result;
    List<RepositoryContent> objRepositoryContentList = content.ToList();

    return Json(objRepositoryContentList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to the use of the async/await you should change the definition of the method `GetRepoTry4` to the following:

```
private static async Task GetRepoTry4()
```

EDIT:
Then in the `Main` method call it like so `GetRepoTry4().Wait();`. This will enable the method `GetRepoTry4()` to be awaited.

Comment: await GetRepoTry4() didn't work since await must be called in async method and Main can't be made async...
I did like you said and changed the call from `GetRepoTry4()` to `GetRepoTry4().Wait`
Worked :) Thank you! :D
New issue now, I think's it's API related... hopefully someone who knows GitHub will see :S

Comment: I have amended my answer to show how to get the async method to work in the `Main` method.